# WiX navigation Access redux store from registered component

Tags: reactjs, react-native, redux, react-navigation, velo

I use WiX navigation with redux.
https://wix.github.io/react-native-navigation/#/usage

In app.jsx file i register all my screens with redux store :

```
const createStoreWithMiddleware = applyMiddleware(thunk)(createStore);
const reducer = combineReducers(reducers);
const store = createStoreWithMiddleware(reducer);
registerScreens(store, Provider);
```

In registerSceens.js i bind the redux store :

```
export default (store, Provider) =>  {
Navigation.registerComponent('aApp.FooComponent', () => FooComponent, store, 
Provider);
}
```

So in FooComponent, how can i easily access to the redux store ?

```
export default class FooComponent extends Component {
constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    console.log(store); //i need REDUX store 
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to connect your component, then you can get the store from the context, something like this:

```
class FooComponent extends Component {
  static contextTypes = {
    store: object,  // <--- allow this component to access the store
  };

  componentWillMount(props) {
     const { store } = this.context; // <-- Get it!!
     console.log(store); //i need REDUX store 
  }
}
export default connect()(FooComponent);
```

Once you have defined the `contextTypes`, you can access the store from `this.context`.

While you can do this... the question is... why would you do something like that? `connect` already allows you to access the state and bind actions, that's usually all you need. As a rule of thumb, is always a good idea to keep our components as dumb as possible.

Answer (score 0):

You need connect your `FooComponent` to redux using react-redux. After that you can access anything via props.

Comment: Hello, add export default connect()(FooComponent) allow to access props.dispatch but how can i access to props.store.subscribe ?

Comment: You need pass the 1st argument of `connect()`. It's a function to map state in your store to props of component.

Your FooComponent:
`const mapStateToProps = (state) => ({
  users: state.users,
});

export default connect(mapStateToProps)(FooComponent);`

After that, you can access `users` via `props.users`.

Comment: And connect() will subscribe for you. Any data change will pass to component via props.